# Read file and format it into dictionary

Tags: python

How to capture the string in **function.py** and track the `def step1()` and its following function `create()` and `login()` into dictionary format?  (***The format i want to achieve is below***)

function.py

```
#!C:\Python\Python39\python.exe
# print ('Content-type: text/html\n\n')

def step1():
    create()
    login()

def step2():
    authenticate()

def step3():
    send()
```

**Expected output**

```
thisdict = {
  'def step1()': ['create(),login()'],
  'def step2():':['authenticate()'],
  'def step3():': ['send()']
}
```

Comment: Read ```function.py```, extract whatever data you need and add it to a dictonary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file `function.py`, split it in order to separate the different functions, and then for each function, split it once more to get the signature as key and the commands as values:

```
with open('function.py', 'r') as inFile:
    funcs = inFile.read().split('\n\n')[1:]
    result = {}
    for elem in funcs:
        sign, commands = elem.split(':')
        commands = list(map(str.strip, commands.split('\n')))[1:]
        result.update({sign : commands})
    print(result)
```

This will return:

```
{'def step1()': ['create()', 'login()'], 'def step2()': ['authenticate()'], 'def step3()': ['send()']}
```

Comment: my function.py first line has some other code
 `#!C:\Python\Python39\python.exe
# print ('Content-type: text/html\n\n')`  
so if will get  error message
 ` sign, commands = elem.split(':')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`  how to ignore the line tat not start with `def`

Comment: @JeraldH'ngShaoJunH'ng edited my code to remove the first two line, based on your sample file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex that would find each method and content `(def \w+\(.*\):)((?:\n[ \t]+.+)+)`

- `(def \w+\(.*\):)` for the method definition
- `\n[ \t]+.+` for each method row (with the previous `\n`)

```
import json
import re

with open("function.py") as fic:
    content = fic.read()

groups = re.findall(r"(def \w+\(.*\):)((?:\n[ \t]+.+)+)", content)
result = {key: [",".join(map(str.strip, val.strip().splitlines()))]
          for key, val in groups}
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that:

```
with open('function.py', 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()

thisdict = {'start':[]}
temp = []
a = '_start_' #just to get the first lines if there is some things before the first function
for line in file:
    if line.startsWith('def'): #You might want to add something for the spacing
        thisdict[a] = temp
        a = line[3:]
        temp=[]
    else:
        temp.append(line)
thisdict[a] = temp

print(thisdict)
```

this clearly isn't the best code but it's easy to understand and easy to implement :)